# Content script not running

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to run a content script attached to a specific HTML page that appears when an error occurs. The webextension is an embedded extension at the moment. The files structure is as follows:

```
- SDK extension [directory]
   - webextension [directory]
     - main.js
     - data [directory]
       - error.html
       - error-script.js
```

Everything runs well except that when I click on the button which should fire the content script, nothing happens. I tried several format for the content script file path in the `manifest.js` `"js": ["webextension/data/error-script.js"]` but nothing changed.

**EDIT:**
The path for the `error.html` when an error occurs contains some automatically generated prefix which does not reflect the actual path:

```
moz-extension://7c92a8c2-219d-4233-a973-c51032e2a375/data/error.html
```

Here is a simple example code:

1) `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "No description.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js","error.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/error.html"],
      "js": ["webextension/data/error-script.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "webRequest"
],

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": {
    "64": "icons/myicon.png"
  },
  "default_title": "example"
},

"hasEmbeddedWebExtension": true
}
```

2) HTML page `error.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
Test.
<input type="button" class="error-button" id="error-button" value="error">
</body>
</html>
```

3) A content script `error-script.js`:

```
var button = document.getElementById("error-button");
button.addEventListener("click",showAlert);

function showAlert()
{
  alert("Error");
}//end function.
```

4) A background script: `error.js`:

```
var target = "<all_urls>";

function logError(responseDetails) {
      errorTab=responseDetails.tabId;
      console.log("response tab: "+errorTab);
      browser.tabs.update(errorTab,{url: "data/error.html"});
}//end function

browser.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(
  logError,
  {urls: [target],
  types: ["main_frame"]}
);
```

Comment: The directory stated in your *manifest.json* will be relative to the directory in which the *manifest.json* file is located. If the *manifest.json* file is in the *webextension* directory, then it would be `"js": ["data/error-script.js"]` or `"js": ["/data/error-script.js"]`. However, it appears that you are attempting to inject a content script into an HTML page which you are loading from within your extension (`data/error.html`). You *can't* inject content script into such pages. You must include the script using a `<script>` element referencing the separate JavaScript file.

Comment: Also, `"hasEmbeddedWebExtension": true` is not valid for *manifest.json* it should be [in your *jackage.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Embedded_WebExtensions#Embedding_the_WebExtension).

Comment: @Makyen can a regular script in `<script> </script>` HTML page access storage API?

Comment: You are loading an HTML page from within your extension. Scripts loaded within that HTML's page run in your WebExtensions' background context, but in the scope of the page you are loading. They have access to all background APIs, and can get access to the scopes of all other scripts which are running in your background context (i.e. all other such scripts, your background scripts, option pages, popups, etc.), just like any other script running in your background context. This includes the `storage` API.